# How to configure ckeditor 5 with ckfinder to browse local directory?

Tags: ckeditor5, ckfinder

I spent half a day today googling, experimenting and failing. I am trying to get ckfinder with ckeditor 5 running. It was quite straightforward with default setup, editor is working, ckfinder pops up with files to browse... I downloaded the bundle from ckeditor website, nothing more.

I went through dozens of pages to find out how to set up the ckfinder base dir for browsing, **kindly note I am currently NOT looking for file upload solution**(there are aplenty online), just a file browser.

I swear I found no configurable parameter that would make ckfinder open a local folder. It always defaults to some CDN/remote server. uploadUrl has no effect on browsing. This setting seems so basic to me that I cannot understand how can it be so difficult to find?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm so stupid. I confess publicly 
I was using the ckfinder from default cdn instead of local install. I will take a break next time and try again next day.